# repo.checkout() : Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout

Tags: python, git, repository, github-api, pygithub

I am using the following code to get the bug fixing commits in a list of GitHub repositories.

```
 def get_commit_bug_fixing(self):
        EMPTY_TREE_SHA = "4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904"
        detected_sml = []
        selected_projects_by_version = pd.DataFrame()
        curr_path = ''
        bug_fixing_commits = self.selected_projects_commits[self.selected_projects_commits['is_bug_fixing'] == True]
        for _, row in bug_fixing_commits.iterrows():
            if row['path'] != curr_path:
                curr_path = row['path']
                g_repo = git.Git(curr_path)
                g_repo.init()
            if row['parent_sha'] == EMPTY_TREE_SHA:
                continue
            g_repo.checkout(row['parent_sha'])
            if row['old_object']:
                detected_sml += util.compute_file_metrics(row['path'], row['old_object'], row['parent_sha'])
            else:
                detected_sml += util.compute_file_metrics(row['path'], row['object'], row['parent_sha'])
                sml_dict = dict(Counter([sml[4] for sml in detected_sml]))
                pre_dict = {}
                pre_dict['sml_name'] = list(sml_dict.keys())
                pre_dict['sml_occs'] = list(sml_dict.values())
                df = pd.DataFrame(pre_dict)
                df['repoName'] = row['repoName']
                df['repoOrg'] = row['repoOrg']
                df['tag_commit_sha'] = row['tag_commit_sha']
                df['tag'] = row['tag']
                selected_projects_by_version = pd.concat([selected_projects_by_version, df])
        selected_projects_by_version.to_csv('bug_fixing_commits.csv', index=False)
```

However, after getting to the `g_repo.checkout(row['parent_sha'])` line I get the following error:

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(1)
cmdline: git checkout 6ada1a2e125f9b40bc38f9d6b69c60e4fe3b7f4e
stderr: 'error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
...list of files path...
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting'
```

How can I resolve this issue? I am not sure what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message, it seems as your are trying to `checkout` another `commit` while your current local repository has some `uncommitted` modifications.

The problem is not your code but your code `algorithm`. Your git operations are missing some steps.

Before doing the line

```py
g_repo.checkout(row['parent_sha'])
```

You may verify if your repository is clean by using

```sh
git status
```

and if the repository is clean you may make the `checkout` otherwise, `commit` (to save) or `discard` (to delete) or `stash` (to save for later) the modifications in the repository before doing any `checkout`.

N.B: Even manually, generally, if you have uncommitted changes in your repository, git refused that you checkout another branch or commit.

Comment: I tried to do this with different commands and run it multiple times but it won't print anything into my CSV file:
            if g_repo.diff() == ' '
                g_repo.checkout(row['parent_sha'])
            else: